# Turn back Android Console version

Tags: android

I upload wrong version in android console, but i save the last one, it is the posibility to turn back into last version? 
I lost the last package, i built a new one package but it is crashing in many old devices.
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you published a wrong apk on you Google Play publish account?

Then there's no way to completely turn back to a previous version, but you can mitigate it. Just make a new publish but instead of drag&drop your apk select it from artifact library.

It should automatically change your wrongly uploaded apk to deactivated and your previous apk to retained Any user that could have download the wrong apk will still have it but at least no more users will download it.

After doing that you should upload a new apk with a new version number fixing the problem

Comment: I do it, and i got this messages that dont let me go ahead: mensajes
1 mensaje para la actualización

Error
No puedes implementar esta liberación debido a que no permite que ningún usuario existente actualice a los nuevos APK agregados.

1 mensaje para APK 400

El APK se sustituyó por completo
Problema:

Ningún usuario recibirá este APK, ya que uno o varios APK con códigos de versión superiores lo sustituyeron por completo.

Resolución:

Quita este APK de tu versión o revisa los códigos de orientación y versión de los APK que incluiste.

Comment: Assumming APK 400 is your wrong APK. Then I guess your only option is to upload a new APK with version number 401 (or any upper number), having the same code as (built with the code of) your previous right APK

But before giving up, just to double check, when you are making a new publish, APK 400 should be set as deactivated. Do NOT click on Retain button for APK 400.

Comment: Same message In spanish: Entonces tu única opción es publicar un nuevo apk con un número de versión superior. Pero antes de desistir comprueba que al seleccionar la APK correcta, la vieja (version code 400) se este desactivando. A la derecha debería poner Conservar (ya que estarías eliminandolo y sólo si pulsas el botón es cuando lo sigues manteniendo y tratarías de publicarlo junto a la anterior. El problema es que si ambas versiones son compatibles en un dispositivo se descarga siempre el más alto). En resumen, no pulses en el botón mantener. Tal vez sea ese tu fallo.